#  How to position dojo tooltip close to text?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Like the title says i want to be able to display the tooltip close to the text, currently it is displayed far away in the cell.

Tobe noted the tooltip positions correctly for large text, only fails for small text.

In DOJO  How can i position the tooltip close to the text?

I have this bit of code snippet that display the  tooltip in the grid cells.

html

```
<div class="some_app claro"></div>
```

.

```
..



          this.createGrid = function () {
            var me = this;
            var options = me.options;


            this.grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid ({

              width: options.width,
              height: options.height,
              query: { id: "*" },
              keepSelection: true,
              formatterScope: this,
              structure: options.columns,
              columnReordering: options.draggable,
              rowsPerPage: options.rowsPerPage,

              //sortInfo: options.sortInfo,
              plugins : {
                menus: options.menusObject,
                selector: {"row":"multi", "cell": "disabled" },

              },


              canSort: function(col) {
                if (options.columns[Math.abs(col)-1].sortable) return true;
                else return false;
              },


              onStyleRow: function (row) {
                var grid = me.grid;
                var item = grid.getItem(row.index);

                if (item && options.rowClass(item)) {
                  row.customClasses += " " +options.rowClass(item);                    
                  if (grid.selection.selectedIndex == row.index) {
                    row.customClasses += " dojoxGridRowSelected";            
                  }    
                  grid.focus.styleRow(row);
                  grid.edit.styleRow(row);     
                }
              },


              onCellMouseOver: function (e){  
              // var pos = dojo.position(this, true);
             // alert(pos);
                console.log( e.rowIndex +" cell node :"+ e.cellNode.innerHTML);
               // var pos = dojo.position(this, true);
                console.log( " pos :"+ e.pos);
                if (e.cellNode.innerHTML!="") {
                  dijit.showTooltip(e.cellNode.innerHTML, e.cellNode);
                }
              },

              onCellMouseOut: function (e){
                dijit.hideTooltip(e.cellNode);
              },

              onHeaderCellMouseOver: function (e){   
                if (e.cellNode.innerHTML!="") {
                  dijit.showTooltip(e.cellNode.innerHTML, e.cellNode);
                }
              },

              onHeaderCellMouseOut: function (e){
                dijit.hideTooltip(e.cellNode);
              },

            });    

       //  ADDED CODE FOR TOOLTIP
        var gridTooltip = new Tooltip({
                connectId: "grid1",
                selector: "td",
                position: ["above"],
                getContent: function(matchedNode){
                    var childNode = matchedNode.childNodes[0];
                    if(childNode.nodeType == 1 && childNode.className == "user") {
                        this.position = ["after"];
                        this.open(childNode);
                        return false;                
                    }
                    if(matchedNode.className && matchedNode.className == "user") {
                        this.position = ["after"];            
                    } else {
                        this.position = ["above"];                               
                    }

                    return matchedNode.textContent;
                }
            });
        ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tooltip is placed around the cell, i.e. `<td>` elements in HTML, not the text. There are two ways out:

A. Use [formatters](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#formatting-a-date-field) to wrap text into an element and place `Tooltip` to this child element of the table cell.

[image]

B. Place `Tooltip` above the cell:

[image]

```
var gridTooltip = new Tooltip({
    connectId: "grid1",
    selector: "td",
    position: ["above"],
    getContent: function(matchedNode){
        return matchedNode.textContent;
    }
});
```

See how both A & B work at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/7F5Cr/

Comment: Yes, you can add the code and it should work. It's more lightweight and very likely faster than hooking to `onCellMouseOver` etc. Can you be more specific w/ the error you are getting? I mean browser, version, OS. I just tested jsFiddle code and it works w/o errors in Chrome 21, 23 & Chrome for iPad; Firefox 15 & 16 beta 2; IE 9 & 10; Opera 12; Safari 5.1.7 & Safari for iPad; Dolphin for Android & iPad.

Comment: I am also noticing its not working on IE9 version9.0.9 and firefox